# Get Items from limited list by providing username and password - C#

Tags: development, list, permissions, authentication

I'm using [this code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.list.getitems.aspx) in order to get items from SharePoint list.

I have a SharePoint list that limited to certain users.
How can I provide by this code (or else) a username and password and login as a different user who has access to this SharePoint list and get its items?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass credentials as follows:

```
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
clientContext.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("Login id", "Password", "Domain");
```